# jQuery and localstorage

Tags: jquery

Right now the following code works, but the notification bar I have disappears if you refresh the page. It should only disappear if the user clicks the close button, but I am not sure how to do that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var showHowTo = localStorage.getItem("firstvisit");
if(!showHowTo) {
    // Stores visit
    localStorage.setItem("firstvisit", true);
    $('#how-to').show();
} else {
    $('#how-to').hide();
}
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("#how-to").hide();
});  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the flag in the close handler

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#how-to').toggle(localStorage.getItem("closeHelp") != 'true');
    $("#close").click(function () {
        $("#how-to").hide();
        localStorage.setItem("closeHelp", 'true');
    });
});
```

Also could use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to simplify the code

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/373uA/)

Answer (score 0):

You are simply hiding it after the user visits the page first time.

You can slightly edit your code, to store the value in `localStorage` not on page load, but when user actually clicks the close button:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var showHowTo = localStorage.getItem("userClosedWindow");
   if (!showHowTo) {          
      $('#how-to').show();
   } 
   else {
      $('#how-to').hide();
   }
   $("#close").click(function(){
       // Stores close button click
       localStorage.setItem("userClosedWindow", true);
       $("#how-to").hide();
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(! showHowTo)`: if the user hasn't visited yet, show how-to (set `showHowTo=true`)

`else` (equivalent to `if (showHowTo)`): the user **has** visited; hide how-to. That is why it disappears if you refresh the page. On reload, `showHowTo` is still true (since you saved it as such in `localStorage`).

To fix this:

```
if (! localStorage.getItem("howToClosed")) {
    $("#how-to").show();
} // no else, because if how-to has been closed, it simply won't show up again
$("close").click(function() {
    $("#how-to").hide();
    localStorage.setItem("howToClosed", true);
}
```